# Ember.js Data how to clear datastore

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am experiementing with Ember.js and have setup a small app where users can login and logout. When the user logs out I want to clear all of the currently cached records in the Data Store. 
Is there a way to do this or would I have to force the browser to reload the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearing the data store is not yet supported in Ember-Data. There is an [open issue concerning this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/235) on the Github tracker.

Comment: That issue is closed, but I still see no method of clearing the store without resetting the application: I need to clear the store for debugging purposes, potentially re-requesting data from the backend, without otherwise affecting the state of my application (I want to stay in the same route, for example). Is this possible?

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is from 2013. But since Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.17 (May 10, 2015) there's a straightforward way of clearing the datastore:

`store.unloadAll()`

(More here: http://emberigniter.com/clear-ember-data-store/)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like, as of today, there is still no generic way of fully forcing a store cleanup. The simplest workaround seems to loop through all your types (`person`, ...) and do:

```
store.unloadAll('person');
```

As seen [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/clear-data-store/3577)

Comment: I don't know when it was introduced but the current documentation states that you can just do `store.unloadAll()` to unload all records.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner & generic approach. Just extend or reopen store & add a clear method like this.

```js
DS.Store.extend({
   clear: function() {
    for(var key in this.typeMaps)
    {
      this.unloadAll(this.typeMaps[key].type);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is:

```
App.reset();
```

But that [does more than clear out the data store](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_reset) and we've occasionally seen errors where `store.pushPayload` tries to push data onto an object marked destroyed from calling `App.reset();`.

Been we've been using:

```
store.init();
```

Which just creates a new empty store and works great but **unfortunately is a private method**.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done with `store.destroy()`.  It unloads all records, but it also available for immediate use in reloading new records.  I have confirmed this as of `1.0.0-beta.15`.  It doesn't appear to be in the documentation, but it's been working for me.

The alternative would be iterating the store's `typeMaps` and running `store.unloadAll(typeMap.typeName)`, but I'm not sure it's entirely  necessary.

Answer (score -2):

Deleting record by record in model. `deleteOrgs` of [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/367/edit):

```
deleteOrgs: function(){
  var len;
  while(len = this.get('model.length')) {
    // must delete the last object first because 
    // this.get('model.length') is a live array
    this.get('model').objectAt(len-1).deleteRecord();
  }
  this.get('store').commit();
}
```

( As of August 2013, there is currently [a problem with lingering deleted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135004/after-localstorage-clear-or-deleterecord-in-my-ember-js-app-local-storage-d). )

Comment: This is deleting the records, which is *way more* than removing them from the store. This is potentially dangerous, causing permanent data loss in the backend ([Delete Records](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/#toc_deleting-records))